# How to create a custom ListView on UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I already set my ListView on C#, the problem is XAML. My current code Works like this :

```
<ListView x:Name="List" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="List_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="11" Width="460">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                    <Image Width="100" Height="100"
                       Source="{Binding Way}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

But I want to do something like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate?  are the top 2 boxes supposed to be one item in your listbox? As it is your code won't compile because of `Source="{Binding Way}"`  OneWay TwoWay?

Comment: @KoryGill that "way" is binding a path to my assets folder,each box is one item of my listview, i tried to use ListBox but i couldn't use the "ItemTemplate". This app show's how i want,but in this case he probably using GridRows [here](https://goo.gl/GD3utN)

Comment: Ahh...that threw me off.

Comment: @KoryGill excuse me?

Comment: I think for UWP you want VariableSizedWrapGrid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your scenario, I think you can use `GridView` instead of `ListView`. [GridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridview.aspx) displays a collection of data in rows and columns while ListView displays a collection stacked vertically.

By default, `GridView` uses [`ItemsWrapGrid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemswrapgrid.aspx) as its [`ItemsPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx), while using `ItemsWrapGrid`, we can set the [`ItemsWrapGrid.MaximumRowsOrColumns`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemswrapgrid.maximumrowsorcolumns.aspx) property with [`ItemsWrapGrid.Orientation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemswrapgrid.orientation.aspx) property to limit the max columns to `2`.

For example:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="GridView_SelectionChanged">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="460" Margin="11">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Image Width="100" Height="100" Source="{Binding Way}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="2" Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
</GridView>
```